# Load dll and host it as windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest, .net-4.0

I have 3 Restful services which I want to host as windows service. I have created one installer which will host all three services together. I want to make my installer a bit configurable. I want to add new services to the same installer without needing it to edit the code.

Here is my current code for the installer. Here I am giving reference to the dll and hosting them. This is just normal code for any windows host project.

App.config file

```
 <services>
  <service name="Service1">
    <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IService1" ehaviorConfiguration="REST"/>
  </service>
  <service name="Service2">
    <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IService2" behaviorConfiguration="REST"/>
  </service>
  <service name="Service3">
    <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IService3" behaviorConfiguration="REST"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="REST">
      <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" helpEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Code in the installer.

```
public partial class Service : ServiceBase
{
    public ServiceHost Service1Host = null;
    public ServiceHost Service2Host = null;
    public ServiceHost Service3Host = null;

    public Service()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {


        Uri Service1_baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9999/Service1");
        Uri Service2_baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9999/Service2");
        Uri Service3_baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9999/Service3");

        if (Service1Host != null)
        {
            Service1Host.Close();
        }
        Service1Host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), Service1_baseAddress);                        
        Service1Host.Open();

        if (Service2Host != null)
        {
            Service2Host.Close();
        }
        Service2Host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service2), Service2_baseAddress); 
        Service2Host.Open();

        if (Service3Host != null)
        {
            Service3Host.Close();
        }
        Service3Host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service3), Service3_baseAddress);
        Service3Host.Open();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (Service1Host != null)
        {
            Service1Host.Close();
            Service1Host= null;
        }
        if (Service2Host != null)
        {
            Service2Host.Close();
            Service2Host = null;
        }
        if (Service3Host != null)
        {
            Service3Host.Close();
            Service3Host = null;
        }
    }
}
```

What I have tried is here. I removed the service endpoint configuration from app.config and did it in code. I put all the dlls in one folder and loading those dlls in code. To get the service and interface I am adding parameters in the app.config as follows which will give the service name and interface name to retrieve from loaded assembly. It all works fine. But I have a little problem, I have explained below.

New App.config file

```
<appSettings>
<add key="Service1.dll" value="Service1"/>
<add key="IService1.dll" value="IService1"/>
<add key="Service2.dll" value="Service2"/>
<add key="IService2.dll" value="IService2"/>
<add key="Service3.dll" value="Service3"/>
<add key="IService3.dll" value="IService3"/>
</appSettings>
```

New Windows host code

```
public partial class Service : ServiceBase
{
    public ServiceHost ServiceHost = null;

    public WinService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Desktop\WindowsHost\dlls", "*.dll");
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            files[i] = Path.GetFileName(files[i]);

        foreach (var dllName in files)
        {
            string filePath = @"C:\Users\Desktop\WindowsHost\dlls\" + dllName;
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(filePath);

            string serviceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[dllName];
            string interfaceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["I" + dllName];

            Type serviceToHost = assembly.GetType(serviceName);
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(serviceToHost);

            Type contract = service.GetInterface(interfaceName, true);

            string address = dllName.Remove(dllName.LastIndexOf("."));

            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9999/" + address);

            if (ServiceHost != null)
            {
                ServiceHost.Close();
            }
            ServiceHost = new ServiceHost(instance, baseAddress);
            ServiceEndpoint sEP = ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(contract, new WebHttpBinding(), "");
            WebHttpBehavior webHttpBeh = sEP.Behaviors.Find<WebHttpBehavior>();

            if (webHttpBeh != null)
            {
                webHttpBeh.AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled = true;
                webHttpBeh.DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json;
                webHttpBeh.HelpEnabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                WebHttpBehavior newWebHttpBeh = new WebHttpBehavior();
                newWebHttpBeh.AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled = true;
                newWebHttpBeh.DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json;
                newWebHttpBeh.HelpEnabled = true;
                sEP.Behaviors.Add(newWebHttpBeh);
            }

            ServiceHost.Open();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (ServiceHost != null)
        {
            ServiceHost.Close();
            ServiceHost = null;
        }
    }
}
```

What I am doing here is creating an instance of the loaded dll and hosting it as a windows service.

```
ServiceHost = new ServiceHost(instance, baseAddress);
```

This works fine if your service behaviour have InstanceContextMode set to single. Else it gives an error.

Error:
**"Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: In order to use one of the ServiceHost constructors that takes a service instance, the InstanceContextMode of the service must be set to InstanceContextMode.Single.  This can be configured via the ServiceBehaviorAttribute.  Otherwise, please consider using the ServiceHost constructors that take a Type argument."**

I tried modifying the code like this

```
ServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(serviceToHost), baseAddress);
```

But it does not work. Please help. Is there any other way to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: That's an interesting approach, but why not simply do one Windows Service per Web Service?  What if something blows up in one of your services and the exception is not caught and handled - you could bring down the Windows Service and all of the hosted web services.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I understand the risk. But this is the requirement. This code works fine. The only problem is I don't have InstanceContextMode set to single for all the services.

Comment: If `Type serviceToHost = assembly.GetType(serviceName)` gives you the class implementing the service (i.e., the class implementing the interface defining the contract), I would try `ServiceHost = new ServiceHost(serviceToHost, baseAddress);` - you already have the type, no need to call typeof again, since the constructor is expecting a `Type` object.

Comment: Tim, You are the man. It is working fine. I had to make few changes in the code though. Had to create an array of ServiceHost. And use it to host all the services. Lets see how long this code holds together. :) Thanks again

Comment: I'm glad you got it working - you might consider posting your final solution as an answer (you can auto-accept it after a time delay) for future devs who might be in the same situation. Also, since you have a single point of failure (being everything's in one Windows Service), I would suggest you look at implementing `IErrorHandler` in your service - that way you can catch any errors that would be otherwise unhandled and reduce the risk of bringing everything down.

Comment: I will surely post the final code. Also. I did some error handling. So right now, Even if one of the service is not hosted it still host other services. I will check with the IErrorHandler as well. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete working code. I have added the endpoint and service behavior as I need. Not everyone will need the same configuration I guess. I take the dll name and append it to the end of the base address. Hence it create new address for each of the service depending on the dll name. The parameters defined in the app.config should match exactly to the name of the dll. For e.g. I am using three dlls as follows then my app.config will be as shown in the below code.

1. Service1.dll
2. Service2.dll
3. Service3.dll

App.config

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="baseAddress" value="http://localhost:9999/"/>
 <add key="Service1.dll" value="namespace.Service1"/>
 <add key="Service1.dll" value="namespace.IService1"/>
 <add key="Service2.dll" value="namespace.Service2"/>
 <add key="Service2.dll" value="namespace.IService2"/>
 <add key="Service3.dll" value="namespace.Service3"/>
 <add key="Service3.dll" value="namespace.IService3"/>
</appSettings>
```

Windows Installer Code

```
public ServiceHost[] serviceHost = null;

    public MyService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {            
        try
        {
            //Get path for the executing assemblly
            string exePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            //Path to the dlls to be hosted
            string filePath = exePath + "\\DLLsToHost\\";
            //Retrieve only dll files from the folder
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@filePath, "*.dll");

            //get the dll file names
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                files[i] = Path.GetFileName(files[i]);

            //create an array of ServiceHost type
            serviceHost = new ServiceHost[files.Length];
            //get the base address for the services from config file
            string address = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseAddress"];

            int j = 0;

            foreach (var dllName in files)
            {
                string dllPath = filePath + dllName;
                //Load the dll
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@dllPath);
                //Get the class name implementing the service
                string serviceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[dllName];
                //get the interface name implemented by the class
                string interfaceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["I" + dllName];

                if (serviceName == null || interfaceName == null)
                {
                    //Log the error
                }
                else
                {
                    //Get the class implementing the service
                    Type service = assembly.GetType(serviceName);

                    if (service != null)
                    {
                        //Get the interface implemented by the class
                        Type contract = service.GetInterface(interfaceName, true);

                        if (contract != null)
                        {
                            //Create a base address for the service
                            Uri baseAddress = new Uri(address + dllName.Remove(dllName.LastIndexOf(".")));

                            if (serviceHost[j] != null)
                            {
                                serviceHost[j].Close();
                            }

                            serviceHost[j] = new CustomServiceHost(service, baseAddress);
                            //add the service endpoint and contract
                            ServiceEndpoint sEP = serviceHost[j].AddServiceEndpoint(contract, new WebHttpBinding(), "");
                            WebHttpBehavior webHttpBeh = sEP.Behaviors.Find<WebHttpBehavior>();

                            //Set the service and endpoint behaviours
                            if (webHttpBeh != null)
                            {
                                webHttpBeh.AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled = true;
                                webHttpBeh.DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json;
                                webHttpBeh.HelpEnabled = true;
                                sEP.Behaviors.Add(new BehaviorAttribute());     //Add CORS support
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                WebHttpBehavior newWebHttpBeh = new WebHttpBehavior();
                                newWebHttpBeh.AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled = true;
                                newWebHttpBeh.DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json;
                                newWebHttpBeh.HelpEnabled = true;
                                sEP.Behaviors.Add(newWebHttpBeh);
                                sEP.Behaviors.Add(new BehaviorAttribute());     //Add CORS support
                            }

                            serviceHost[j].Open();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Log the error
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Log the error
                    }
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //Throw the exception OR Log it
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        try
        {
            for (int k = 0; k <= serviceHost.Length - 1; k++)
            {
                if (serviceHost[k] != null)
                {
                    serviceHost[k].Close();
                    serviceHost[k] = null;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions to update the code are welcome. Thanks.